# Getting Initialization error when running Junit test

Tags: junit, initialization

I was trying to run a very simple Junit test and i was geeting initialization error.

[error page on eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imFik.png)

Answer (score 1):

The test method must be a public void method without any argument

```
@Test
public void sumOfABlankStringIsZero() {
    assertEquals(0, Calculator.sum(" "));
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. It would be nice if you accept the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer